# could not find compatible versions for gem "rubyzip"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caracal

I am using

**gem 'axlsx_rails'**

**gem 'acts_as_xlsx'**

for downloading file into excel.
Now I am trying to add the following gem

**gem 'caracal'**

for downloading file into docx.
Whenever, I am trying to run

**bundle install**, I got the following error

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rubyzip":   In
>   snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       rubyzip (= 1.0.0)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       acts_as_xlsx was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
>         axlsx (>= 1.0.13) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
>           rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
>
> ```
> caracal was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
>   rubyzip (~> 1.1)
> ```
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
>   only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

My gem file looks like following

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '4.1.9'
>
> gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.19'
>
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
>
> gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
>
> gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'
>
> gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
>
> gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
>
> gem 'spring',        group: :development
>
> gem 'devise'
>
> group :development do
>
> gem 'better_errors'
>
> gem 'binding_of_caller'
>
> gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.1'
>
> gem 'capistrano-rails'
>
> gem 'capistrano-bundler'
>
> gem 'capistrano-rvm'
>
> end
>
> gem 'therubyracer'
>
> gem 'less-rails'
>
> gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '3.2.0'
>
> gem 'cancan'
>
> gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
>
> gem 'rmagick'
>
> gem 'caracal'
>
> gem 'activerecord-session_store', github:
>   'rails/activerecord-session_store'
>
> gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0'
>
> gem 'wicked'
>
> gem 'figaro'
>
> gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
>
> gem 'axlsx_rails'
>
> gem 'acts_as_xlsx'

Comment: How exactly (including version numbers) does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: I have added the Gemfile @spickermann

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding

> gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.1.0.pre'

in the gem file. This gives an error first then I had to update rubyzip. After that I run

> bundle install

Answer (score 0):

The [`axlsx_rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx) gem hasn't been updated for quite a while and it depends on a version of the `axlsx` gem that depends on a `1.0.x` version of the `rubyzip`. Whereas [`caracal`](https://rubygems.org/gems/caracal) depends on a version `>= 1.1`. That said: Current versions of that gem will not work together.

But an even older version of the [`axlsx 1.3.6`](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx/versions/1.3.6) had a more relaxed dependency to the `rubyzip` gem - it only requires its version to be `>= 0.9.5`.

Therefore I suggest - if possible - to downgrade `axlsx_rails` to `0.1.2` and try again:

```
# add a version to the axlsx_rails gem in your Gemfile
gem 'axlsx_rails', '0.1.2'
```

And run `bundle install` again.

Comment: caracal is not installed yet. The above command shows the following error-



Could not find gem 'caracal'.

Comment: Still no luck. Now says- Could not find gem 'axlsx_rails (>= 1.3.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: @jisan I am sorry, I mixed up version numbers. I updated my answer. Please try again.